# How to read a local html file from phone memory using webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, local

I need to make an apk file wherein a webview will load an html5 file which is not in the assets folder. The html5 file is located in the phone memory. This is my code.

```
private WebView web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webV);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Download/index.html";
    web.loadUrl(url);
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
     @Override
     public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
         handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
     }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It doesn't read the path that I indicated in my code. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
  } else {

    web.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/index.html");
 }

Comment: Make sure your available into your specified path.